# How do you convert "top-level await of dynamic import" to "synchronous require" in a Typescript-based project targeting both ESM and CJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, es6-modules

I'm working on creating a small Node.js library, with source written in TS, and (ideally) the generated JS distributed in both ESM and CJS formats.

It has a peer dependency (currently as CJS) where I need to detect if it's installed, and if not provide a fallback before continuing. Because of this, I can't statically import it, and seem to need to use dynamic `import` in the ESM distribution and `require` in the CJS distribution to detect that instead.

To avoid the dynamic `import` alone forcing me to export a Promise onto consumers, I was thinking of using top-level `await` in the ESM distribution (since it's been supported unflagged since Node 14.8.0 and the use case here is similar to [this one from the tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await#dependency-fallbacks)). So the generated JS would look like

ESM:

```
try {
    peerExport = await import("the-cjs-peer-dependency") //Notice this isn't inside of an async block
}
```

CJS:

```
try {
   peerExport = require("the-cjs-peer-dependency")
}
```

Right now I have 2 tsconfig.json's, one for ESM and one for CJS, and my source TS looks exactly like the ESM version of the generated JS.

What I'm struggling with is how to replace the `await import`'s with `require`'s in the CJS build process, as TS immediately gives a hard-stop that CJS doesn't support top-level await and won't continue. I haven't found anything so far in Typescript's settings either that would enable this substitution, only this [related Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43329) for a reversed problem of wanting to keep dynamic imports of ESM modules from CJS ones as-is.

My current plan is to add pre-/post-build steps to scan my TS source and do a find-and-replace, then run the tsc, then revert the source, though this doesn't seem great. Any ideas on this specific problem or the larger one of trying to support ESM/CJS out of a single TS source codebase would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well,, there is no top-level-await for CJS.  So, unless your asynchronous code can be rewritten with synchronous operations (like for file access), then you're just out of luck.  You can't simulate top level await in CJS so if that's your ESM design, then your CJS design will have to work differently and present a different way to initialize the module.

Comment: Yeah in my specific case here just rewriting them to use require should be enough (I'm not using top-level await for anything other than importing modules right now)